# reading logfile and opening files in there

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm having a problem reading a logfile I'm creating in another method.
The logfile has file-paths of unzipped files in it (unpacking is in another function). The logfile looks kinda like this

```
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/XXX.something
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/YYY.something
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/AAA.something
```

---

```
@staticmethod
def iterate_log(path):
    results = str()
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            results += '%s\n' % os.path.join(dirpath, name)
    with open(os.path.join(EXTRACT_PATH_, LOGNAME_), 'w') as logfile:
        logfile.write(results)
        return os.path.join(EXTRACT_PATH_, LOGNAME_)

@staticmethod
def read_received_files(from_file):
    with open(from_file, 'r') as data:
        data = data.readlines()
        for lines in data:
        # to reduce confusion I would use
        # for line in data:
            read_files = open(lines)
            print(read_files)
            return read_files
```

Now I want to read the logfile line by line (the parameter `from_files` in the second method is the return value of the first method right now) and open those files and return them (for using them elsewhere).
`readlines()` and `read()` are both giving me errors so far

```
readlines() = [Errno2] No sucht file or directory: '/../../../logfile.log\n

read() = IsADirectoryError: [Errno21]
```

whole traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "files_received_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "files_received_test.py", line 9, in main
    j = Filesystem.execute_code(FILENAME_)
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/Projektgruppe/code/src/filesystem_hasher.py", line 16, in execute_code
    Filesystem.read_received_files(create_log)
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/Projektgruppe/code/src/filesystem_hasher.py", line 54, in read_received_files
    read_files = open(lines)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/unpacked_files.log\n'
```

Comment: You're using relative paths so check what is the current directory

Comment: Actually another problem might be that you need to strip the line return '\n'

Comment: Besides, these are not really the error messages that Python generates, are they? Include the real stack trace instead.

Comment: Now, look at it yourself. Do you really have the file `/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/unpacked_files.log\n` (with newline in the name)?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev no of course i dont :). I'm quite new to python. is there a way to remove the newline character?

Comment: use the strip(), the file name is a string and strip() will remove the newline character from the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to strip the newline character so change

```
read_files = open(lines)
```

to

```
read_files = open(lines.strip())
```

as an observation - critical to read each character in an error message - the message was telling you that there was no file named

```
'/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/unpacked_files.log\n'
```

so it is useful to then try to understand why the \n showed up - this did not match your expectation of the file name so you should wonder why the file has that name

Comment: yes you're right. the `strip()` seems to work here. One last question. Does the return statement `return read_files` really return all the files or did i make a mistake there as well :)

Comment: @user3688267  You should inspect it, I think it is returning one at a time.  You do something interesting and a bit naive.  So you have for lines in data.  lines is actually referring to a single line - so whatever the first line is in data is what is being processed.

Comment: Sorry for being a glory hog but if you found my answer useful then the convention is to mark it up (pressing the arrow above the 0).  It it answered the question you answered then you should click the check mark.  That is how I get rewarded for taking the time to help.

Comment: thanks for replying :). I will mark it as solved but I'm curious in what way i did something interesting and naive at the same time. if you would enlighten me a last time that would be nice. I want to improve so pointing it out would be nice! Edit: you're saying that the first line is being processed. The other lines are not opened and returned?

Comment: My read of your code is that only the first line is being returned, it is interesting because I never thought of having a plural construct in programming, it would be possible if you developed the right grammer, so lines would be to process all and line would be to process singly, it is Naive - no insult intended - because it seems you are expecting the plural form to control execution

Comment: well the function of this class should be  the following. I want to unzip an archive. then access all unzipped files and read/open them. ( that's what we have been working on here ). Then i want to "return ALL files in the directory where it was unzipped so I can use a hashfunction on each file to get the hashvalue of the file. so this function has to return all of the files not just the first one. The hash procedure is in another separate class. is that somehow possible?

Comment: It is but you need to ask another question - SO for good reason likes to keep questions and answers focused.  It helps people find answers better

Comment: You're right. I created a different question for that different problem! Thank you tho :)