# access logfile and return/open all files written in there

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971854/reading-logfile-and-opening-files-in-there)

I have a python class which is supposed to unpack an archive and recursively iterate over the directory structure and then return the files for further processing. In my case I want to hash those files. I'm struggling with returning the files. Here is my take.
I created an unzip function, a function which creates a log-file with all the paths of the files which were unpacked. Then I want to access this log-file and return ALL of the files so I can use them in another python class for further processing.This doesn't seem to work yet.

Structure of log-file:

```
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/XXX.log
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/XXX.py
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/XXX.py
/home/usr/Downloads/outdir/Code/XXX.py
```

Code of interest:

```
@staticmethod
def read_received_files(from_log):
    with open(from_log, 'r') as data:
        data = data.readlines()
        for lines in data: 
            \\ This does not seem to work zet
            read_files = open(lines.strip())
            return read_files
```

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the extracted file? For what purpose are you calculating their hash?

Comment: @mhawke well the plan is on hashing files and then saving the hash with other file related meta data in a database. so you can look up or compare hashes from newly hashed files. so the Idea was to write a class where the unpacking and accessing of the files for further processing is done

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's what you're looking for:

```
@staticmethod
def read_received_files(from_log):
    files = []
    with open(from_log, 'r') as data:
        for line in data:
            files.append(open(line.strip()))

    return files
```

You returned while iterating, preventing from opening the other files.

Comment: I tried it with your input and when printing the `files` the output is a list ( obviously ) where the entries look like this: `<_ioTextIOWrapper name='/../path/....... mode='r' encoding='utf-8'>` . That way I can hand over that list to another class and process them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are primarily after the meta data and hash of the files stored in the zip file, but not the file itself, there is no need to extract the files to the file system.

Instead you can use the `ZipFile.open()` method to access the contents of the file through a file-like object. Meta data could be gathered using the `ZipInfo` object for each file. Here's an example which gets file name and file size as meta data, and the hash of the file.

```
import hashlib
import zipfile
from collections import namedtuple

def get_files(archive):
    FileInfo = namedtuple('FileInfo', ('filename', 'size', 'hash'))
    with zipfile.ZipFile(archive) as zf:
        for info in zf.infolist():
            if not info.filename.endswith('/'):  # exclude directories
                f = zf.open(info)
                hash_ = hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest()
                yield FileInfo(info.filename, info.file_size, hash_)

for f in get_files('some_file.zip'):
    print('{}: {} {} bytes'.format(f.hash, f.filename, f.size))
```